# Phone stopped connecting to Wireless

Tags: iphone, wifi

iPhone 5: Since yesterday my phone stopped working to wireless at work.
I asked other people and no one had issues with connecting to wireless.
I went home and no issues with connecting to home wireless either.
So it is just me and my phone having issues connecting to work wireless.

What troubleshooting steps do you suggest? I tried the "forget this network" and re-joining it again but that didn't solve it.

**UPDATE**
: One thing I found out is that when I am at my desk with whatever router they have around that area, my wireless doesn't work. But when I go to kitchen area with whatever router they have in that area, it connect and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings`.

From the docs:

> This will reset all network settings including:
>
> - previously connected Wi-Fi networks and passwords
> - recently used Bluetooth accessories
> - VPN and APN settings

More information about troubleshooting WiFi networks is available here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1398

Comment: Thanks I did this right now and still getting "unable to connect to work_wirelss" message :(

Comment: One thing I found out is that when I am at my desk with whatever router they have around that area, my wireless doesn't work. But when I go to kitchen area with whatever router they have in that area, it connect and works fine.